# convert an R script to IDL: Array manipulation

Tags: r, idl-programming-language

I am an R and IDL beginner. Im trying to convert an R script to IDL.

R can do array manipulation with t1 (array[100000]) but IDL cannot.

> ERROR: Array subscript for CZ must have same size as source expression

```
s1= 100000.

c1 = array[200000]

n1 = s1*2+2

t1 = array[100000]

————————————————————————————————

(function)

f03, c1, s1, n1



cz = fltarr(n1,3)       

cz[0:((2*s1)-1),0] = c1

cz[1:(2*s1),1] = c1

cz[2:((2*1)+1),2] = c1

cr = cz[0:(n1-1),1] - cz[0:(n1-1),2]

cl = cz[0:(n1-1),1] - cz[0:(n1-1),0]

p1 = where(cr GE 0.0 AND cl GE 0.0 AND (cz[0:(n1-1),1]) GE 1.4)



n2 = n_elements(p1)

ct = fltarr(n2+1,2)

ct[0:n2-1,0] = p1 

ct[1:n2,1] = p1

c2 = ct[*,0] - ct[*,1]

ip = where(c2 GT 2.) 

ch = p1[ip]



return, ch
```

————————————————————————————————

```
p1 = f03(c1,s1,n1) ;;;;; function works here

f1 = f03(t1,s1,n1)  ;;;;; error on array size
```

I used MATRIX and AS.MATRIX in R (for f03). Does FLTARR cause this error?

Comment: Help! :( Can somebody help me. :(

Answer (score 0):

Your lines:

```
cz = fltarr(n1, 3)
cz[0:((2 * s1) - 1), 0] = c1
```

make sense when `cz` has a first dimension of size 2000002 and `c1` is 200000 elements — the sizes on the left and right of the `=` sign match, i.e., `0:199999` is 2000000 elements just like the size of `c1`.

But in the second call, `c1` only has 100000 elements, but the left side is still asking for 2000000 elements.

Also, define a function like:

```
function f03, c1, s1, n1
  ; a bunch of code goes here
  return, ch
end
```

Comment: Thank you so much mgalloy. yes, that is the problem. but i do not know how to solve it. 
Anyway, thank you so much.